# why i datagridview.currentcell wouldn't position the cursor in the desired cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

For the testing purposes, i have added a simple datagridview `datagridview2` control with two columns on to a form. then i have used to `Load()` event of the form to add an empty row to the **datagridview** and written the following code to place the cursor in the first cell.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add();

    //dataGridView2.BeginEdit(true);

    //dataGridView2[1, 0].Selected = true;
   // dataGridView2.Select();
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2[0,0]; //.Row(1).Cells(0)
    //dataGridView2.Focus();
    dataGridView2.BeginEdit(false);

}
```

i have tried the `Focus(`), `Selected` property and `Select()` with `CurrentCell` and `BeginEdit()`. But this **does not place the cursor in the first cell**.

[Here is the video capture of the form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbSzBLUsaPQ&feature=youtu.be)

PS- I have an original installation of VS 2010 ultimate (WITHOUT any service packs). I was wondering this could be the problem. But Could anyone point me where the problem is?

Comment: Um, the form hasn't even been displayed when the `Load` event handler is executed so how can you start editing a cell?  Try doing that in the `Shown` event handler, which is executed after the form is displayed, and you should see what you expect.

Comment: @jmcilhinney your instruction worked! thanks

Comment: @jmcilhinney, any specific reason for not posting that as answer.

Comment: @Rahul, I felt like it wasn't a complete answer as it was but, having reread the question, I'm satisfied that it is so I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, the form hasn't even been displayed when the Load event handler is executed so how can you start editing a cell? Try doing that in the Shown event handler, which is executed after the form is displayed, and you should see what you expect.